# How to take folder path in a variable opened by shell:startup in windows

Tags: windows, shell, script

Hi i am trying to create a script that can add other scripts in startup.

'shell:startup' opens place to put the shortcut for startup programs, if i can somehow take its output in a variable, then i don't have to worry about taking different startup folder path for different versions of windows

Comment: this is actually a good idea.  what language , dos or powerhsell?

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik For now windows, but we need to support all major platforms-linux,windows,mac. A .bat script will be very good, i think i can translate it to python code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current user's start-up folder (where `shell:startup` leads you) can be located with variables as such:

Batch:

```
"%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

Example of putting the whole thing into a variable and using it:

```
set userStartup="%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
echo %userStartup%
```

PowerShell:

```
"$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

Example:

```
$userStartup = "$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
write-output $userStartup
```